Outsourcing of ckeditor5 files with TYPO3 13.3
As an example of how to adjust files of the ckeditor5 with TYPO3, I'd like to extend the special-characters-plugin with my own glyphs (which works in the vendor-file but will be lost after updating the core).
I have a custom configuration
in my ext_localconf.php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['ub_sitepackage'] = 'EXT:ub_sitepackage/Configuration/RTE/ckeditor-ub.yaml';
and page.tscofig
RTE.default.preset  = ub_sitepackage
My preset is loading and some basic adjustements show up and work as expected.
My idea to adjust the special-chars to my need was to move the ckeditor5-special-characters.js-file to my sitepackage
ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript
If I got it right, I need an entry in /Configuration/JavaScriptModules.php of ub_sitepackage (probably because of JavaScript ES6 reasons)
<?php

return [
    'dependencies' => ['core', 'backend'],
    'imports' => [
        '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/' => 'EXT: ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/ckeditor5-special-characters.js'
        ],
        ]
        

In my yaml-configuration I import the file
editor:
  config:
    importModules:  
      - { module: '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/ckeditor5-special-characters.js' }
      
  

The button is added to the toolbar
toolbar:
  items:
   ...
   - specialCharacters    

After clearing cache ckeditor uses the original file. If I commenting out the line
    //'@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/Contrib/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters.js',
    

in the vendor-JavaScriptModules.php the button don't show up anymore.
Thanks in advance for your help

I would recommend to register your own plugin with its own name, see https://www.derhansen.de/2023/05/2023-05-05-create-a-custom-ckeditor5-plugin-for-typo3-12.html for an example. Otherwise clashes might easily occur and the internal plugin might take precedence.

Hi,
thank you for your instant reply. Where and how could I do this? Maybe helpfull: The dev-tools of my browser shows the error message Failed to load CKEditor5 module @ub-company/ub_sitepackage/ckeditor5-special-characters.js TypeError: Der Spezifizierer "@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/ckeditor5-special-characters.js" war ein blanker Spezifizierer, wurde aber nicht zu etwas neu zugeordnet. Relative Modulspezifizierer müssen mit "./", "../" oder "/" beginnen

Did you check out the blog post that goes through the module assignment in detail? Specifically your 'imports' identifier is missing the filename.

I checked the post, but I could not find out, what I've overlooked. I've tried many variations of - { module: '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/ckeditor5-special-characters.js' , like - '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/ckeditor5-special-characters.js' and without file suffix.
The example from https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/main/en-us/Configuration/Examples.html works. Other manually implementations of other extensions like wbr-plugin from https://github.com/sebkln/linebreak also don't work. I don't know where I can "./", "../" oder "/".  Could it be a problem with TYPO3s CSP?

CSP could theoretically be a problem, yes. Did you check your browser network panel and see if the JS files get requested, and if they yield a CSP error?

I have just tried this with TYPO3 v13.4-dev, and it is the same solution as outlined in the blog entry. I'll try to write up some caveats:
I called my TYPO3 extension ckeditorplugin.
1. Create EXT:ckeditorplugin/Resources/Public/JavaScript/timestamp-plugin.js:
import * as Core from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core';
import * as UI from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui';

export default class Timestamp extends Core.Plugin {
    static pluginName = 'Timestamp';

    init() {
        console.log('timestamp init.');
        const editor = this.editor;

        // The button must be registered among the UI components of the editor
        // to be displayed in the toolbar.
        editor.ui.componentFactory.add(Timestamp.pluginName, () => {
            // The button will be an instance of ButtonView.
            const button = new UI.ButtonView();

            button.set( {
                label: 'Timestamp',
                withText: true
            } );

            //Execute a callback function when the button is clicked
            button.on('execute', () => {
                const now = new Date();

                //Change the model using the model writer
                editor.model.change(writer => {

                    //Insert the text at the user's current position
                    editor.model.insertContent(writer.createText( now.toString()));
                });
            });

            return button;
        });
    }
}

Important things to note:

export default class Timestamp - this is important, and needs to create a UNIQUE plugin name here. The default export is important to note, too.
The same plugin name needs to be used everywhere where Timestamp is placed (5 occurences in total)
If you copy an existing CKEditor plugin to take on as your own, ensure you use a unique NEW plugin name.

2. Create EXT:ckeditorplugin/Configuration/JavaScriptModules.php:
<?php
return [
    'dependencies' => ['backend'],
    'tags' => [
        'backend.form',
    ],
    'imports' => [
        '@myself/ckeditorplugin/timestamp-plugin.js' => 'EXT:ckeditorplugin/Resources/Public/JavaScript/timestamp-plugin.js'
    ],
];

Things to note:

The identifier must be formatted like @(anyvendorname)/(typo3-extensionkey)/(anyfilename).js. It needs to be unique, and you should match your vendorname and typo3-extensionkey with the actual TYPO3 extension naming.

3. Adapt your CKEditor YAML to add the plugin:
editor:
  config:
    importmodules:
        # ...
        - '@myself/ckeditorplugin/timestamp-plugin.js'

Things to note:

The identifier needs to be EXACTLY THE SAME as you defined in your JavaScriptModules.php
You need to ensure you edit the right CKEditor YAML to add the key
Add the key with a dash and do not use a notation for it like - { module: '@myself/ckeditorplugin/timestamp-plugin.js', exports: [ 'Timestamp' ] } - because my example does NOT use an export (it uses a default export).

4. Adapt your CKEditor YAML to add the plugin:
editor:
  config:
    toolbar:
      items:
        # ...
        - '|'
        -  Timestamp

Things to note:

Use exactly the identifier as you used inside the file timestamp-plugin.js as the identifier of the plugin name. This must be unique and not clash with any internal CKEditor plugin.

5. Execute composer dumpautoload, flush TYPO3 cache
This is very important, without the 'dumpautoload' command, a newly added file to Resources/Public/ will NOT be available to be requested via HTTP. Flushing the TYPO3 cache is required to interpret the javascript import maps.
6. Flush Browser Cache
This ensures that any possible earlier variant of the JS files you created are updated.

Thank you for your detailed help. The example you described (which looks like the one form https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/main/en-us/Configuration/Examples.html) is the only one that works for me. What I don't understand is, why the others don't. As a proof of concept, I 'doubled' the timestamp-example by copying the js-file and renamed it to timestampzwo-plugin.js - everything else adopted of course( imports, toolbar, static pluginName = 'Timestampzwo'; and so on ); but the button don't show up.
I can't notice errors on the dev-tool-network panel - everything statuscode 200

Coold you zip up the extension you tried, I can try to reproduce this then maybe and spot the issue?

Thank you very much for your persistent help. The link contains the ext., based on sitebuilder-package for v12 with nothing in but the ckeditor-things. Note the js-files in the public-folder The link should be available for the next 6 days
https://filebin.net/e7tera4id3uysf8z.

Alright, I will definitely check this out. It  may take me until Tuesday though. I've downloaded the link!

(see my second answer; several issues found in the files)

This answer is in response to comment Outsourcing of ckeditor5 files with TYPO3 13.3 because inside comments I cannot properly format my answer.
In the ZIP file delivered, there were several issues:

Prefixes did not fully match, for example one plugin was referred to as "@woit/wit-loremipsum/lorem-ipsum.js" in the Default.yaml file, but in JavaScriptModules.php it was registered as "@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/lorem-ipsum.js"

In JavaScriptModules.php there were multiple 'imports' PHP array keys. They rule each other out, if an array key is redefined.

Plugins like 'WordBreak' or 'SpecialCharacters' would clash with existing CKEditor definitions, so they would need to be renamed to 'ubWordBreak' and 'ubSpecialCharacters' for example.

The file "ckeditor5-special-characters.js" did not match the one that is delivered with TYPO3 v13 in its declaration. Also, now that I've looked at it, you are editing a minified JavaScript file, which has several issues (readability being one of them). You would have to do several modifications to the file to make it be able to be included:

Replace "special-characters" with "ub-special-characters", replace "specialCharacters" with "ubSpecialCharacters", replace "SpecialCharacters" with "ubSpecialCharacters"
Use the "ubSpecialCharacters" button key then in YAML
Change the "C as ubSpecialCharacters" export to "default als ubSpecialCharacters"


The YAML definition should load the modules with 'default' exports (or others) in mind


With the files listed below, I got it to work. However, the CKEditor plugin currently only lists "All" as category and none of the others. That would require you to inspect the plugin how it works to register that dropdown. It probably clashes with the existing SpecialCharacters plugin. You should really not unbundle a CKEditor plugin like this, instead I would recommend to write a proper, custom CKEditor plugin for your use case. That is much less hassle, because patching a minified file will always lead to trouble. And you will always need to match your custom implementation over what CKEditor delivers as default.
Default.yaml:
# YAML:
editor:
  config:
    importModules:
      - { module: '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/timestamp-plugin.js', exports: [ 'Timestamp' ] }
      - '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/ckeditor5-special-characters.js'
      - '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/wordbreak.js'
      - '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/lorem-ipsum.js'

# ...

    toolbar:
      items:
        - timestamp
        - ubWordbreak
        - loremIpsum
        - ubSpecialCharacters
        - '-'
        - style
        - heading

JavaScriptModules.php:
<?php
return [
    'dependencies' => ['backend' ],
    'tags' => [
        'backend.form',
    ],
    'imports' => [
        '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/timestamp-plugin.js'                => 'EXT:ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/timestamp-plugin.js',
        '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/ckeditor5-special-characters.js'    => 'EXT:ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/ckeditor5-special-characters.js',
        '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/wordbreak.js'                       => 'EXT:ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/wordbreak.js',
        '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/lorem-ipsum.js'                     => 'EXT:ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/lorem-ipsum.js',
    ],      
];

ckeditor5-special-characters.js:
See https://gist.github.com/garvinhicking/5c41108e4861fdc20ad7baa6b44802cd
wordbreak.js:
Changed "WordBreak" to "ubWordBreak" (4 replacements)

Thank you for your dedication and persistent support!
"@woit/wit-loremipsum/lorem-ipsum.js" - your're right; overlooked in the hurry to make the zip.file.
In JavaScriptModules.php there were multiple 'imports' PHP array keys. They rule each other out, if an array key is redefined. - That was a very useful hint.
With your support Timestamp, wordbreak and loremipus work as wanted. SpecialCharacters - With your file and the declarations in Default.yaml and JavaScriptModules.php the button for my custom-specialChars shows up, popup opens but nothing to choose.
JavaScriptModules.php
<?php

return [
    'dependencies' => ['backend' ],
    'tags' => [
        'backend.form',
    ],
    
    'imports' => [
        '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/timestamp-plugin.js'                => 'EXT:ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/timestamp-plugin.js',
        '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/ckeditor5-special-characters.js'     => 'EXT:ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/ckeditor5-special-characters.js',
        '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/wordbreak.js'                       => 'EXT:ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/wordbreak.js',
        '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/lorem-ipsum.js'                     => 'EXT:ub_sitepackage/Resources/Public/JavaScript/lorem-ipsum.js',
    ],      
];

Default.yaml
editor:
  config:
    debug: true
    
    importModules:
      - { module: '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/timestamp-plugin.js', exports: [ 'Timestamp' ] }
      - '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/ckeditor5-special-characters.js'
      - '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/wordbreak.js'
      - '@ub-company/ub_sitepackage/lorem-ipsum.js'
  
    toolbar:
      items:
        - timestamp
        #- wordbreak
        - ubWordbreak
        - ubSpecialCharacters
        - loremIpsum
        - '-'
        
        
        
    ubSpecialCharacters: 
      order: 
        - 'ubSpecialCharactersCustom' 
        #- 'Custom' 
        - 'ubSpecialCharactersArrows'
        #- 'Arrows'
    ...


Maybe it has something to do with content security. See dev-Tools console form Browser. The Screenshot is from TYPO3 v12 but the same in v13.3

The TYPO3 csp module csp module
[

Yes, I noticed that too. I believe the plugin does some "weird stuff" and is not meant to be "ripped out" and re-attached to another ES6 submodule. Sadly I myself can't help more on the JS side of that module.
